# Click event created with RxJs gets emitted more times than native click event

Tags: angular, rxjs

I need to distinguish between short (< 400ms) and long (> 400ms) clicks. I've implemented both events with RxJs, but the short click is emitting way more than it should if the user starts to click fast on the element.

**app.component.html**

```
<button #button (click)="onBuiltInClickEvent()">Click</button>
<p>Method was called: {{ calledTimes }}</p>
<p>Native click was called: {{ nativeClick }}</p>
```

**app.component.ts**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  @ViewChild("button")
  public button: ElementRef;

  public calledTimes: number = 0;
  public nativeClick: number = 0;

  private mouseDown$: Observable<MouseEvent>;
  private mouseUp$: Observable<MouseEvent>;
  private click$: Observable<MouseEvent>;

  public ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.mouseDown$ = fromEvent(this.button.nativeElement, "mousedown");
    this.mouseUp$ = fromEvent(this.button.nativeElement, "mouseup");

    this.click$ = this.mouseDown$.pipe(
        flatMap(_ => {
            return this.mouseUp$.pipe(timeoutWith(400, EMPTY));
        })
    );

    this.click$.subscribe(_ => this.onClick());
  }

  private onClick(): void {
    this.calledTimes++;
  }

  public onBuiltInClickEvent(): void {
    this.nativeClick++;
  }
}
```

[image]

Working [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-q6kiwe).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`flatMap` wouldn't be the suitable map operator in this scenario. You do not wish to flatten (or merge) the inner observable. In this scenario, only one inner subscription should be active at a time. So you could use [`switchMap`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/switchMap) operator.

I also see that you aren't handling the error from the timeout or resubscribing to the observable if it times out. You could use RxJS `retryWhen` operator for that. Try the following

```js
this.click$ = this.mouseDown$.pipe(
  switchMap(_ => this.mouseUp$.pipe(
    timeout(400),
    retryWhen(e => of('timeout error'))
  ))
);
```

I've modified your [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-heujv8)

Comment: It works like a charm. But I'm wondering when that error can occur? Can you please explain to me that part a bit?

Comment: Differences b/n `flatMap` (aka `mergeMap`) would be little detailed to explain here. A quick hint to the source of the problem here is when using `flatMap`, it wouldn't wait for the inner subscription to complete before subscribing again. So there would multiple processes in parallel. `switchMap` operates by unsubscribing the previous observable before subscribing to a new one. So there would only be one active process. You could learn more here: https://blog.angular-university.io/rxjs-higher-order-mapping/